# .htaccess rewrite request when the_request starts with string in list

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to implement the following Rewrite rule(s) in an .htaccess file (Apache Webserver), but have no idea where to start and what is the best approch. 
But it should actually do the following:

## psuedo-code:

```
  if (path begins with "patternA", "patternB" or "PatternC") {

      if (path matches "patternA")
          redirect to /xxxxxx-a
      else if (path matches "patternB")
          redirect to /xxxxxx-b
      else if (path matches "patternC")
          redirect to /xxxxxx-c             
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /patternA [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /xxxxxx-a [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /patternB [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /xxxxxx-b [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /patternC [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /xxxxxx-c [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Works as a charm :) :)

Comment: Can you use <If instead of RC and RR?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `NC` and `R` are just flags

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) are a good place to start, look for RewriteRule.

Basic examples:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^patternA /xxxxxx-a [L]   # internal redirect, invisible to visitor
RewriteRule ^patternB /xxxxxx-b [R,L] # external redirect, visible to visitor
```

etc.  You may need to add AllowOverride to your httpd conf to allow .htaccess files to be used.